# Change names of all files in a directory?

Tags: file, cmd, filenames, file-rename

I am using Windows 7 64-bit Home Edition. I have over a 100 files in a folder that start with a certain string. I wish to remove this string.

> Example: abc_file1.txt, abc_file2.txt, abc_file3.txt and so on. I want
>   the filenames to be changed to file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt etc.

But, manually doing this stuff takes a lot of time. Is there any easier and faster method to achieve this.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Comment: Thanks @user55449, the [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is a really powerful tool. Not only removing the strings, I could do a hell lot of stuff with it. Could you write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I've never used it (and don't even use Windows), so I don't think I could write a good answer. You could write and accept your own answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am overwhelmed by the response received by everyone. Since I don't have a solid programming background, I was in search of a simplistic approach or rather an automated software that could do it for me.

The [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is an awesome software that not only does string removal, rather a whole lot of stuff which would take me hours to do manually.

Answer (score 2):

I created rename.bat in same directory as the abc_*.txt files.

rename.bat

```
echo off
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do rename "abc*.txt" "////*.txt"
```

Sample Run

```
C:\Users\jgosalia\Desktop\directory>dir

 Directory of C:\Users\jgosalia\Desktop\directory

07/12/2017  11:40 PM    <DIR>          .
07/12/2017  11:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 abc_file1.tx
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 abc_file2.tx
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 abc_file3.tx
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 abc_file4.tx
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 abc_file5.tx
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 abc_file6.tx
07/12/2017  11:39 PM                64 rename.bat
               7 File(s)             64 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  269,494,484,992 bytes free

C:\Users\jgosalia\Desktop\directory>rename.bat

C:\Users\jgosalia\Desktop\directory>echo off

C:\Users\jgosalia\Desktop\directory>dir

 Directory of C:\Users\jgosalia\Desktop\directory

07/12/2017  11:40 PM    <DIR>          .
07/12/2017  11:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 file1.txt
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 file2.txt
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 file3.txt
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 file4.txt
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 file5.txt
07/12/2017  11:35 PM                 0 file6.txt
07/12/2017  11:39 PM                64 rename.bat
               7 File(s)             64 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  269,494,484,992 bytes free

C:\Users\jgosalia\Desktop\directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python for it .

```
import os

def renaming_all_files():
     file_list=os.listdir(r"C:\example\directory")
     for file_name in file_list:
     os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,"abc"))

renaming_all_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way in PowerShell.

```
$ps = 'abc_'
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter ${ps}*.txt |
    ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $($_.Name -replace $ps,'') }
```

It can be called from a .bat script.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "$ps = 'abc_'; Get-ChildItem -File -Filter ${ps}*.txt | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $($_.Name -replace $ps,'') }"
```